# How do you expand an array on BigQuery to add columns to the existing table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently I'm having problems with expanding an array provided in a BigQuery table.

Is it possible to create another table or view that expands all of the items inside the `msgs` column into another table. I have provided the screenshot below

How would I do this?

Here is a query to get all tables and columns from my table

`` SELECT * FROM `aftership.shipments` ``

Here is a list of the data types

**Field Name, Type, Mode**

```
_id,STRING,NULLABLE 
_index,INTEGER,NULLABLE 
_created,TIMESTAMP,NULLABLE 
_fivetran_synced,TIMESTAMP,NULLABLE 
_ip,STRING,NULLABLE 
event,STRING,NULLABLE   
event_id,STRING,NULLABLE    
is_tracking_first_tag,BOOLEAN,NULLABLE  
msg,STRING,NULLABLE 
ts,INTEGER,NULLABLE
```

Sample data from the msg column would be

```
{
    "id": "gynv1fsa8m7amkoct4zvx00w",
    "tracking_number": "KEX99999999",
    "title": "#xx589",
    "note": null,
    "origin_country_iso3": "THA",
    "destination_country_iso3": "THA",
    "courier_destination_country_iso3": "THA",
    "shipment_package_count": null,
    "active": false,
    "order_id": "3753237577781",
    "order_id_path": null,
    "order_date": "2021-05-06T01:09:01Z",
    "customer_name": "คุณx xxx",
    "source": "shopify",
    "emails": ["jonappleseed@gmail.com"],
    "smses": ["+669999999"],
    "subscribed_smses": [],
    "subscribed_emails": [],
    "android": [],
    "ios": [],
    "return_to_sender": false,
    "custom_fields": {
        "item_names": "เซต x & x x x x 1"
    },
    "tag": "Delivered",
    "subtag": "Delivered_001",
    "subtag_message": "Delivered",
    "tracked_count": 26,
    "expected_delivery": null,
    "signed_by": "คุณxxx xx #32589",
    "shipment_type": null,
    "created_at": "2021-05-06T11:29:54+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-07T09:00:32+00:00",
    "slug": "kerry-logistics",
    "unique_token": "deprecated",
    "path": "deprecated",
    "shipment_weight": null,
    "shipment_weight_unit": null,
    "delivery_time": 2,
    "last_m…
```

[Aftership. Shipments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBx53.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What column do you want to add?  What is the logic?  Are all those columns needed to answer the question?  Perhaps you could ask a question with a *clear* explanation, along with sample data and desired results (perhaps simplified) to illustrate the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, my question is I would like to convert the string provided above, which is an example of a row under the 'msg' column into columns in another table.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is transform your JSON_string into a `STRUCT` containing the fields you're interested in (the `STRUCT` is not necessary, but keeps things organised):

```
WITH sample AS (
    SELECT "1" AS id, "{\"id\":\"gynv1fsa8m7amkoct4zvx00w\",\"tracking_number\":\"KEX99999999\",\"title\":\"#xx589\",\"note\":null,\"origin_country_iso3\":\"THA\",\"destination_country_iso3\":\"THA\",\"courier_destination_country_iso3\":\"THA\",\"shipment_package_count\":null,\"active\":false,\"order_id\":\"3753237577781\",\"order_id_path\":null,\"order_date\":\"2021-05-06T01:09:01Z\",\"customer_name\":\"\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13x xxx\",\"source\":\"shopify\",\"emails\":[\"jonappleseed@gmail.com\", \"jonappleseed@yahoo.com\",\"jonappleseed@outlook.com\"],\"smses\":[\"+669999999\"],\"subscribed_smses\":[],\"subscribed_emails\":[],\"android\":[],\"ios\":[],\"return_to_sender\":false,\"custom_fields\":{\"item_names\":\"\u0e40\u0e0b\u0e15 x & x x x x 1\"},\"tag\":\"Delivered\",\"subtag\":\"Delivered_001\",\"subtag_message\":\"Delivered\",\"tracked_count\":26,\"expected_delivery\":null,\"signed_by\":\"\u0e04\u0e38\u0e13xxx xx #32589\",\"shipment_type\":null,\"created_at\":\"2021-05-06T11:29:54+00:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-05-07T09:00:32+00:00\",\"slug\":\"kerry-logistics\",\"unique_token\":\"deprecated\",\"path\":\"deprecated\",\"shipment_weight\":null,\"shipment_weight_unit\":null,\"delivery_time\":2}" AS msg
)

SELECT id,
    STRUCT(JSON_VALUE(msg, '$.id') AS mid,
    JSON_VALUE(msg, '$.title') AS title,
    JSON_VALUE(msg, '$.tag') AS tag,
    JSON_VALUE(msg, '$.active') AS is_active,
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(JSON_QUERY(msg, '$.emails')) AS emails,
    JSON_QUERY(msg, '$.custom_fields') AS custom_fields) AS msg
FROM sample
```

This gives

[image]

(The additional mails were not in the original mail, I added them to show that you can extract an array from your JSON string into an ARRAY in THE STRUCT).

You just have to add a line for every field you ahve interest in, following the template:

```
JSON_VALUE(msg, '$.<FIELD>') AS field_column
```

NB: JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY depending on what you want